# Is there an any option to get a file unique by Etag in minio

Tags: minio

I am currently making some progress in MinIO. Is there any way I can get the object by an `Etag` which is available for each object after uploading.. so that I can **identify the thing uniquely!!**

The existing way am using is to get the object only by mentioning the bucket name and the exact object name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no get object by Etag under S3 API. The correct way to get object is via its object name or version id(optional given versioning is enabled)

Comment: Yes !! I was too aware of that, but curious to know if there is a way to get an object by Etag. Anyhow Thanks for your reply...